# Create an Active Navigation class link Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navigation

i am trying to create an active navigation on my Rails 7  app. So far it works well but when I navigate further down the path Like to Show a particular user details or policy details the active class doesn't apply. I am using Rails Helper to make this work.

this is what  it looks like
[image]

when I click on the policy to show the particular policy the active class link goes away.

[image]

I want the active link for policy to remain even when I navigate further into Policy views

this is the code on the Sidebar

```
<li>
          <div class="text-xs font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-400 px-6">Governance</div>
            <ul role="list" class="-mx-2 space-y-1">
              <li class="">
                <%= link_to users_path,  :class => current_class?(users_path) do%>
                  <svg class="h-6 w-6 shrink-0" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M15 19.128a9.38 9.38 0 002.625.372 9.337 9.337 0 004.121-.952 4.125 4.125 0 00-7.533-2.493M15 19.128v-.003c0-1.113-.285-2.16-.786-3.07M15 19.128v.106A12.318 12.318 0 018.624 21c-2.331 0-4.512-.645-6.374-1.766l-.001-.109a6.375 6.375 0 0111.964-3.07M12 6.375a3.375 3.375 0 11-6.75 0 3.375 3.375 0 016.75 0zm8.25 2.25a2.625 2.625 0 11-5.25 0 2.625 2.625 0 015.25 0z" />
                  </svg>
                  People
                <%end%>
              </li>
              <li class="">
                
                <%= link_to policies_path, :class => current_class?(policies_path) do%>

                  <svg class="h-6 w-6 shrink-0" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M15.75 17.25v3.375c0 .621-.504 1.125-1.125 1.125h-9.75a1.125 1.125 0 01-1.125-1.125V7.875c0-.621.504-1.125 1.125-1.125H6.75a9.06 9.06 0 011.5.124m7.5 10.376h3.375c.621 0 1.125-.504 1.125-1.125V11.25c0-4.46-3.243-8.161-7.5-8.876a9.06 9.06 0 00-1.5-.124H9.375c-.621 0-1.125.504-1.125 1.125v3.5m7.5 10.375H9.375a1.125 1.125 0 01-1.125-1.125v-9.25m12 6.625v-1.875a3.375 3.375 0 00-3.375-3.375h-1.5a1.125 1.125 0 01-1.125-1.125v-1.5a3.375 3.375 0 00-3.375-3.375H9.75" />
                  </svg>
                  Policies
                <% end %>
              </li>
```

while the helper code looks like this

```
 def current_class?(active_path)
        if request.path == active_path
            return "text-white group flex gap-x-3 rounded-md p-2 text-sm leading-6 font-semibold hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-800 bg-blue-900 px-6"
        else
            return "text-gray-400 group flex gap-x-3 rounded-md p-2 text-sm leading-6 font-semibold hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-800 px-6"
        end

    end
```

Answer (score -1):

i was able to fix this by including in the helper method this line of code

```
if request.path.starts_with?(active_path)
```

this uses the path that begins with the active path passed through the method